Expressing the binomial theorem as a derivative
In Reichl's statistical physics book, there is a derivation of the mean number of $+1$ outcomes, when you do $N$ independent trials, where each only results in two outcomes ($+1$ or $-1$):
$$\langle n_+ \rangle = \sum_{n_+=0}^Nn_+P_N(n_+)= \sum_{n_+=0}^N\frac{n_+N!}{n_+!(N-n_+)!}p^{n_+}q^{N-n_+}=p\frac{\partial}{\partial p}(p+q)^N=pN(p+q)^{N-1}=pN$$
Given, $p+q =1$
Can somebody please explain to me how she goes from a discrete sum to a continuous derivative (step 3 --> 4)?
I know that the Binomial theorem gives us: $$\sum_{n_+=0}^N\frac{N!}{n_+!(N-n_+)!}p^{n_+}q^{N-n_+}=(p+q)^N$$
But there is an extra $n_+$ term in the series above.

$n_+p^{n_+} = p\frac{\partial}{\partial p} p^{n_+}$ then pull the derivative out of the sum, as nothing else depends on $p$. Then use the binomial theorem
